# Iterate over large data fast with Python?

Tags: python, database

I'm doing data analytics on medium sized data (2GB, 20Mio records) and on the current machine it hardly fits into memory. Windows 7 slows down considerably when reaching 3GB occupation on this 4 GB machine. Most of my current analysis need to iterate over all records and consider properties of groups of records determined by some GroupID.

How can approach this task? My current method is to load it into SQLite and iterate by row. I build the groups in-memory, but this too grows quite large.

I had the following ideas, but maybe you can suggest better approaches:

- sort SQLite table by GroupID so that groups come in together
- store data somehow column-wise so that I don't have to read all columns
- serialize data to parse it faster with Python?

These ideas seem hard to combine for me :( What should I do?

(PS: Hardware upgrades are hard to get. Admin right are cumbersome, too)

Comment: What format is the data stored in? CSV files can be iterated over quite easily.

Comment: It all depends on: data format, data specifics (like, how many group ids you have), what kind of aggregation you want.

Comment: SQL is precisely the language to deal with this. Why do things in code when it can be better done in SQL or stored procedure (closer to the data)?

Comment: What aggregations are you trying to achieve? Many of them can be transformed into online-learning problems that only require only O(1) memory at any point in time.

Comment: One of my operations is: For each GroupID collect all pairs of value/type fields, e.g. gid1:[(v1,t1), (v2,t2), ...]. Next I have multiple selectors s1, s2 which sub-select from this list depending on tn. For example s1 will sub-select s1:[(v2,t2), (v5,t5)]. Finally, in this selection the set {v2,v5} is examined by all of the filters f1, f2, ... (each makes multiple checks if one or none of vn falls into some range). A count (s1,f2) is generated, if filter f2 is True for sub-selection s1.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say anything without knowing more about the data & aggregation you are trying to do, but definitely don't do `serialize data to parse it faster with Python` -- most probably that's not where the problem is. And probably not `store data somehow column-wise so that I don't have to read all columns`.

`sort SQLite table by GroupID so that groups come in together` <- this sounds like a good approach. But lot of aggregations (like count, average, sum etc.) don't require this. In this type of aggregation, you can simply hold a map of `(key, aggregation)`, and iterate through the rows and iteratively apply them to the aggregation (and throw the row away).

Are you currently gathering all rows that belong to a group in-memory and *then* doing the aggregation? If so, you might just need to change the code so that you do the aggregation as you read the rows.

**EDIT:**  In response to the comment:
If that's the case, then I'd go for sorting. SQL might be an overkill though if all you do is sort. Maybe you can just write the sorted file on disk? Once you do that you could look into parallilizing. Essentially you'll have one process reading the sorted file (which you don't want to parallelize as long as you don't do distributed processing), which packages one group worth of data and sends it to a pool of processes (the number of processes should be fixed to some number which you tune, to avoid memory shortage) which does the rest of processing.

Comment: I gather (k1, [a1, a2, ...]), (k2, [a3, ...]), ... and then I apply the aggregation as described in the comment above. Even this uses up too much memory and slows down Windows considerably. Only with pre-sorting I could throw away the intermediate data. Any insight on how to speed up IO and find a good balance between in-memory and hard-disk would be great.

Comment: @Gerenuk: Added a response, HTH